# Execution time of a repeatedly executed multi-threaded C++ method without instrumenting code

Tags: c++, linux, performance

I have a C++ application on Linux, which receives continuous stream of data and processes this data in multiple threads.
The main() method of the application starts N threads that receive data stream.
Each thread does the following until no more packets are to be received.

1. receive packet.
2. call process(packet) method.

I need to trace the execution time(in ms) of the process() method throughout the runtime of the application. See how the execution time varies throughout the runtime. I need to do it in a way that the performance of the application is not affected by the logic of computing the execution time. The application will run for a long time, hence I cannot indefinitely store execution times for all packets in-memory. Many tracing tools I have come across like perf, gprof give the latency breakdown in terms of percentage of execution time, but not the actual execution time in ms. The C++ application I am working on is supposed to be a low-latency application.

Comment: This is usually done by explicit instrumentation, using a special metrics collecting library, such as https://github.com/jupp0r/prometheus-cpp or https://opentelemetry.io/. Though, to be honest, C++ is not the best supported language for this sort of things.

Comment: I know of only two methods to measure performance: instrumentation and sampling. Sampling, while reducing the accuracy, might also affect your latency. Why do you reject the instrumentation?

Comment: I think I will go with gprof for now Since instrumentation adds more code, I believe it will result in slowdown.